# How do I put away my weapons in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I know this is likely a very silly question, but I'm new to the game. Which button do I press to put away my drawn weapons in Skyrim?  I'm playing the game on the Xbox 360.

Answer (score 4):

[Press X](http://www.gamefly.com/game/xbox-360/Elder-Scrolls-V-Skyrim/146235/GameplayControls/), the same button you use to ready your weapon, to [sheathe it](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Controls).